# Count files in ZIP's directory

Tags: php

```
<div id="head">

<?php 
$dir = opendir('uploads/'); # This is the directory it will count from
$i = 0; # Integer starts at 0 before counting

//While false is not equal to the filedirectory
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) { 
    if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..') and !is_dir($file)) $i++;
}

echo "There were $i files"; # Prints out how many were in the directory
?>
</div>
```

Comment: So, what's is your question exactly?

Comment: i want to caluclate howmany files are in my "zip files" ,, i want code for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) instead:

```
$i = count(glob('uploads/*')) - count(glob('uploads/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR));
```

Comment: ohk tnx.................

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`fnmatch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) function inside your loop for matching file names like this:

```
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) { 
    if (fnmatch('*.zip', $file)) {
        ++$i;
    }
}
```

But the same patterns are understood by [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) too.